# Activate css only for specific users

Tags: css, asp.net

I've got an element in an HTML page (an image button), that has a css that shows something when a mouse hovers on it.
I would like the css to be activated only for certain users - that is, I've got a login control on the page as well, so I want the css to be activated only for specific usernames.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use different stylesheets, and load them up depending on which you want:

```
<%
if user=thisguy then
%>
<link href="css/style_thisguy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<%else%>
<link href="css/style_thathuy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<%end if%>
```